# Rename variable holding matrix as combination string

Tags: python, join, matrix, concatenation, naming

I was wondering how I could name a matrix variable.

Let's say the matrix a

```
var=din3
a
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

I want to concatenate the name of the variable with a string.

I want to do something like this: a+"IM"+var

so that the resulting variable would be aIMdin3.  So when I call aIMdin3 I get the matrix, instead of calling a.

How could I do this?

Comment: Dynamic naming of variables is a bad idea. You can get just about all the benefits without the problems by using a dictionary. Instead of using a variable name you rather use a dictionary key. So instead of using `alMdin3` you use `mydict['alMdin3']`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to dynamically create variable by playing with globals(), but I wouldn't recommend this type of "meta-programming"
In my humble opinion, it's best to use dictionary instead and generating your dynamic variables by creating dynamic keys to your dictionary.

```
var = "din3"
d = {}
d['aIM'+var] = a
```

For more details, visit [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)